# How to parse json data in a column with Druid SQL?

Tags: sql, json, apache-superset, druid

I'm trying to parse json data in a column with Druid SQL in Superset SQL lab. My table looks like this:

| id | json_scores |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | {"foo": 20, "bar": 10} |
| 1 | {"foo": 30, "bar": 10} |

I'm looking for something similar to `json_extract` in MySQL e.g.

```
SELECT *
FROM my_table 
WHERE json_extract(json_scores, '$.foo') > 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

Druid doesn't support `json_extract` function. Druid supports only ANSI SQL 92, which does not understand JSON as a data type.

Supported data type are listed in this page: https://docs.imply.io/latest/druid/querying/sql-data-types/

You can use any expressions that are listed here: https://druid.apache.org/docs/latest/misc/math-expr.html#string-functions

In your case consider using `regexp_extract`:

```
regexp_extract(json_scprs, '(?<=\"foo\":\s)(\d+)(?=,)', 0) AS foo,
```